# How do I write multiple functions in one file?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing my own Jenkins shared library. Currently my lib looks like this:

```
root
|
|- vars
   |---function1.groovy
   |---function2.groovy
   |---function3.groovy
```

Each function file contains a `call()` method and the code that it is executing. How can I combine all those functions in one file?

Comment: You can define multiple global variable methods in one file if you wish. You can place them all in the same file as opposed to multiple files if you want. This would be a code organization practice. This is outlined in the documentation: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables. Do you have a question around code organization best practices or some other subtlety? As the question is written, the literal answer is to take the content from each file and place it into one file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put all functions into single file:

```
root
|
|- vars
   |---allFunctions.groovy
```

Rename functions from `call()` to:

```
function1(string) {
  echo "function1 - $string"
}

function2(string) {
  echo "function2 - $string"
}
```

Call them from different file (e.g. `vars/buildRepo.groovy`) as:

```
allFunctions.function1('Hello world via function1')
allFunctions.function2('Hello world via function2')
```

Call them from withing same file (e.g. `vars/allFunctions.groovy`) as:

```
function1('Hello world via function1')
function2('Hello world via function2')
```

As @matt-schuchard noted, it is described in https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables on `log.groovy` example.